# Count the number of distinct items that repeat n times in a range

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, repeat

I have a list of numbers where some repeat in Excel. I would like to count how many times any number repeats a specific number of times.

For example, if I have the following array

```
5
6
1
3
1
2
2
3
1
3
4
5
```

and I want to know how many times any number repeats 3 times, excel would output 2, since 1 and 3 both repeat 3 times but no other values do. Is there a way to easily do this in excel? Preferably without having to check for each number individually.

Comment: print substr_count('1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1', 1); **Use this function**

Comment: If you have an array then use **array_count_values()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula counts the number of items that repeat more than two times in the range `A1:A12`. The items can be numbers or strings, no matter. It can apply to any range.

```
' count the number of items that repeat 3 or more times
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12)>2)/COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12))
```

[image]

If you want the number of repetitions to be *exactly 3*, just change `>2` into `=3` (column E in the example figure).

An interesting particular case is to count the number of distinct values in the range, as in column C in the shown example. One can change `>2` into `>0`, but it can be further simplified:

```
' To count the number of distinct items in a range
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12))
```

The example below shows the calculation of all the examples stated above, *separately* (no helper columns were used for any of them).